# Odoo docker image: how to scaffold?

Tags: python, ubuntu, docker, cmd, odoo

When you install the [Odoo (version 10) docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/odoo/), how to reproduce [this command](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/howtos/backend.html):

```
odoo-bin scaffold openacademy addons
```

Comment: Actually it is a problem I faced during a development process: I installed Odoo 10 from the source and I developed a module for it and installed it. Now I want to redo the same work on the Odoo Docker image instead. The command above creates the basic skeleton for the module I will program with.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do scaffolding from the Docker host with this command:

```
docker exec unkkuri-odoo /usr/bin/odoo scaffold openacademy /mnt/extra-addons
```

In this command "unkkuri-odoo" is the name of the Odoo container. You have to have the container running when you run this scaffolding command. Another important thing is the folder used for addons. In Odoo docker the place for addons is in /mnt/extra-addons.

You can also do scaffolding manually by executing bash in the container and doing scaffolding like in any other Odoo environment inside the container. Start bash like this:

```
docker exec -ti unkkuri-odoo bash
```

And scaffold in container like this:

```
/usr/bin/odoo scaffold openacademy1 /mnt/extra-addons
```

Comment: When I tried the second option (bash), I saw both modules ! That is really a great help ! All what I have to do now is to check where I can document myself about the command you shared. Thank you a lot.

Comment: You are looking at the right place and both ways should be producing scaffolded module under /mnt/extra-addons. How did you check the contents in the first case? Do you have persistent volume set for /mnt/extra-addins? If you do not have persistency and you recreate the container you will lose module content.

Answer (score 1):

In Odoo 15 with Docker, you should run command:

```
docker exec -ti odoo odoo scaffold /mnt/extra-addons/custom_module
```

My repository to run Odoo 15 on docker-compose:

https://github.com/dylanops/docker-odoo